# Can't export MariaDB large table by mysqldump when row_format is compressed

Tags: mariadb, mysqldump, mariadb-10.2

I have a MariaDB 10.2.13 server. This server contains a database called 'factory'. This database contains a table called 'client'. This is a large table.

client table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `client` (
  `id` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `lastname` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `address1` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `time` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `comment` longtext NOT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `product_idx1` (`address1`),
  KEY `product_idx3` (`address2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=4
```

I wanted to export the table by the mysqldump instruction as follows:

```
mysqldump factory --quick --complete-insert --no-create-db --no-create-info --skip-extended-insert --compact --tables client --max_allowed_packet="3G" > dump_client.sql
```

Then I got the error message as follows:

```
mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table `client` at row: 1002046
```

I was trying to check the record by the SELECT Statement as follows:

```
SELECT * from client limit 1002046,1'
```

Even though, I didn't see anything irregular in data. I think it is happening when ROW_FORMAT is COMPRESSED.
I can't change the ROW_FORMAT because it's a requeriment.

Added 1:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout';
+-----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name               | Value |
+-----------------------------+-------+
| connect_timeout             | 60000 |
| delayed_insert_timeout      | 300   |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout | 1     |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout    | 360   |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout  | OFF   |
| interactive_timeout         | 28800 |
| lock_wait_timeout           | 86400 |
| net_read_timeout            | 120   |
| net_write_timeout           | 900   |
| slave_net_timeout           | 60    |
| thread_pool_idle_timeout    | 60    |
| wait_timeout                | 28800 |
+-----------------------------+-------+
```

product table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `comment` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `parentId` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `countryId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stateId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expireDate` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `supervisorName` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `planDate` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `canceledDate` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `cancelReason` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `warranty` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `productEdition` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `productCode` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `condition` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `productAlias` varchar(2000) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `productName` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `productAliasId` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timeCreated` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `operator` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `productStoreId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `productApplication` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `product_idx2` (`operator`),
  KEY `product_idx4` (`subjectDN`(255)),
  KEY `product_idx5` (`type`),
  KEY `product_idx6` (`supervisorName`,`condition`),
  KEY `product_idx7` (`countryId`),
  KEY `product_idx11` (`productAliasId`),
  KEY `product_idx12` (`productCode`,`productAliasId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8;
```

What can I do for this case?

Answer (score 0):

"Lost connection ... during..." means that there was a timeout.

Compressed data is uncompressed right after reading, so the dump should work (baring the timeout).

Comment: If there was a timeout. What is the appropiate option/argument for mysqldump?

Comment: I look at how many seconds it ran before timing out, then look at `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout';` to see what to increase.

Comment: I wrote the 'Added 1:' in the post. I looked the timeout for client table backup and it lasted 19 seconds. On the other hand, I added in the post a second large table structure called 'product'. I looked the timeout for product table backup and it lasted 9 seconds. So the timeouts are variable and I don't see relationship with results from SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout'.

Comment: @user3637971 - Hmmm... 19 and 9 are short.  I was expecting 300 or thousands.  Is there something unusual about the network connection?

Comment: There's no unusual about network connection. I checked mysql log and It showed me corruption messages on table index. The database is the result of backuping. This backup consist of copying ibd files by linux command. It's happening for tables are being inserted by applications

Comment: @user3637971 - Copying the `.ibd` is _not_ sufficient for backup+restore.  There is information in `ibdata1` that is not saved+restored.  Also. without flushing the buffer_pool, you have no control over what is waiting to be written to the `.ibd`.

Comment: Is it necessary to backup the ibdata1 file if the innodb_file_per_table property is enabled?

Comment: Search for "transportable tablespaces" for the workaround.